# Runtime Exception: The assembly with display name 'Catel.MVVM.Aero' failed to load

Tags: catel

I'm quite new to Catel and .NET development and is now working on some minor improvements on an existing project. I noticed that I got some runtime exceptions and that is something I do not like to have in my code. Thus I started to investigate what caused these. The first I get is "BindingFailure". To try to isolate the problem I created the most simple Catel application; a main window with an empty viewmodel and I still get this exception. When I start it I get this runtime Exception:

```
The assembly with display name 'Catel.MVVM.Aero' failed to load in the 'Load' binding
context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Catel.MVVM.Aero,
Version=3.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
Det går inte att hitta filen.
```

(The last sentence is Swedish and means "File not found".) I cannot see what I'm doing wrong. Am I using the framework in the wrong way? Have I missed something?

I'm using Catel 3.9.0 and the Core package and the MVVM.

Here is my code:

The MainWindow.xaml:

```
<catel:DataWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
        >
</catel:DataWindow>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using Catel.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : DataWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1.ViewModels
{
    using Catel.MVVM;

    /// <summary>
    /// UserControl view model.
    /// </summary>
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Constructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainWindowViewModel"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the title of the view model.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The title.</value>
        public override string Title { get { return "View model title"; } }

        // TODO: Register models with the vmpropmodel codesnippet
        // TODO: Register view model properties with the vmprop or vmpropviewmodeltomodel codesnippets
        // TODO: Register commands with the vmcommand or vmcommandwithcanexecute codesnippets
    }
}
```

Comment: Just saw the template for creating a WPF Application with Catel, even just that application gives this runtime exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "normal". You have probably enabled the "break on all exceptions" and this is an internal exception that happens when loading the aero theme. Just hit continue and it will work fine.

Comment: Yes, I saw some exceptions in the output and was not sure if I'm causing them or not and coming from Java I'm very cautious to not have any Exceptions at all. So how can I judge which ones are "normal"?

Comment: Geert refers to First Chance Exceptions (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/07/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-), which allow Visual Studio to break even on handled exceptions. To learn how to fine-tune this behaviour check http://florianreischl.blogspot.pt/2010/01/how-to-enable-first-chance-exceptions.html.